# Lookup Category ID from Name

Tags: category

I have a list of category names, and I was wondering if there a way in Magento to lookup the category id using the name? Please advise the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Regina Nickles,you can do this by loadByAttribute();

### For single category:

```
$category=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('name',$name);
$id=$category->getId();
```

### For getting multiple categories

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            //->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('name',array('like'=>$name));

 $allIds = $collection->getAllIds();
```